# Making live-usb without sudo

Tags: 18.04, live-usb

I have 2 questions about making a bootable USB flash drive:

1. Is the initial format of the USB is important?
    Few months ago I burned Ubuntu 18.04 iso file - using dd command - into an ext4 formatted 8 GB USB. But not only it didn't boot, it corrupted unrecoverable BIOS of my old laptop. I don't want something similar happen to the new one. I know that FAT32 is the recommended format.But it does not work with USBs larger than 4GB.
2. Is there any way to make a bootable USB without sudo ?
    The initial installation of Ubuntu on my new laptop was corrupted after an unsuccessful update and there is only a default user on the recovered system for which I don't have the password.

Comment: 1. You can make a USB boot drive with different methods and different file systems. A USB boot drive with Ubuntu does not destroy the BIOS of the computer. It does not tamper with it at all; 2. Yes, you can make a bootable USB without sudo, provided that there is already a suitable partition table and file system for the method, that you want to use (and that method works without using sudo). But according to my experience the most reliable method to create a USB boot drive with Ubuntu is **cloning**, and this method requires sudo. Please tell me if you want more details (links).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know about various methods for making bootable USB. But they need either sudo or a computer with Windows to use e.g. Rufus or similar utilities. After considering various options I think the latter is the safest one.

Comment: Rufus works well (if you stay away from the experimental persistence). Good luck :-)

Comment: It worked !! Rufus is quite simple to use. I wished there were a similar utility in ubuntu,

Comment: The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator is easy to use, maybe even easier than Rufus. It is a cloning tool (and uses elevated permissions). It helps you identify the target drive in a good way to avoid mistakes, and the result is very reliable. If you want a more advanced tool, that can do more things, you can try mkusb (that I developed and maintain). It is also safe and reliable, but a bit more difficult to use. I am cooperating with a developer from the 'Debian world' to develop a new  tool, that should be even safer (helping the user to avoid writing to the wrong device).